# Adding xml-stylesheet at the second line of the xml string

Tags: java, xml

how to add style sheet at the second line of the xml file, i have write the code but it add the style-sheet on the first line of my xml String file, please see my code it is working code but it add the stylesheet at the first line of xml string and my requirment is to add xml-stylesheet at the second line of xml string please help

```
public class StringToDocumentToString {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws TransformerConfigurationException {
        String xmlstring = null;
        String filepath = "E:/C-CDA/MU2_CDA_WORKSPACE/AddingStylesheetTOxml/documentfile.txt";
        final String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                + "<Emp id=\"1\"><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age>\n"
                + "<role>Developer</role><gen>Male</gen></Emp>";

        Document doc2 = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);
        Document doc1 = null;
        try {
            doc1 = addingStylesheet(doc2);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str = convertDocumentToString(doc1);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    private static <ProcessingInstructionImpl> Document addingStylesheet(
            Document doc) throws TransformerConfigurationException,
            ParserConfigurationException {

        ProcessingInstructionImpl pi = (ProcessingInstructionImpl) doc
                .createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet",
                        "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"cda.xsl\"");
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        doc.insertBefore((Node) pi, root);
        return doc;

    }

    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            // below code to remove XML declaration
            // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,
            // "yes");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
            return output;
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before transforming

```
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
```

try with the below output properties,

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i have made that changes which you suggested and my code give me the expected result. thanks

Comment: Welcome! Glad you got the results.